# Phalcon PHP - Register Dependency Injection

Tags: php, dependency-injection, phalcon

Im trying to create simple registration form. When a user submits the form it posts the data to the controller and from there variables are assigned to the fields the user entered.

The problem is that i dont want to use the php functions __POST and so on.

Phalcon have there own functions etc for this which also Sanitizes the data.

The problem is that when i submit the form it says "A dependency injection object is required to access the 'filter' service"

This is the documentation page http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/filter.html

But it does not say how to inject this into Phalcon.

I tried something basic like

```
        $di->get('filter', function () use ($di) {
        $filter = new Phalcon\Filter();
        $filter->setDI($di->getDI());
        echo("->".$filter->getQuery('id', 'int', 0));
    });
```

But its still not working.

Please help!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed -> instead of using $this-$request and assigning a variable for $request i simple used "$this->request->etc"